# How to represent the distance between each image pixel and a contour in color?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Here is the code I used

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('circle.png' )
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgblured = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgray , (5,5) , 0)
_,threshold = cv2.threshold(imgblured,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU )


_,contours,_=cv2.findContours(threshold , cv2.RETR_LIST ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print 'number of contours is : ' , len(contours)
cnt = contours[0]
cv2.drawContours(img , [cnt] , -1 , (255,255,255),20)
```

This part represents distance by color. I think I need more help.

```
for i in range  ( img.shape[0]):
    for j in range  (img.shape[1]):
        dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest( cnt ,(i,j)  , True)
        if dist > 0 :
            img[i,j] =[j,0,0]
        elif dist == 0 :
            continue
        else :
            img[i,j] =[0,0,j]
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can use some Color Maps available in opencv or you could write your own! Here is a sample implementation! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427189/generate-a-heatmap-from-blobs-different-sizes-using-c/32431163#32431163

Comment: @BalajiR that is awesome !!!